# How to structure common module so the sub-modules can get the right type of objects from the APIs?

Tags: java, gradle, module, structure

Hey so I have `common` module that contains code show bellow and two additional modules `bungee` and `bukkit`. How would I need to structure my code so that I could use `common` part of code in each module but to not have to cast `Object` in the `ChildCommand` to `CommandSender`, is there a way to actually get the right `CommandSender` there instead of `Object`?

**Some things to keep in mind:**
`common` module has no dependencies.
`bungee` module uses Bungeecord API and `common` module as a dependency.
`bukkit` module uses Bukkit API and `common` module as a dependency.
Bukkit and Bungeecord APIs both have its own `CommandSender` class but they are not the same.
Classes that come from the APIs cant be modified.

**This classes are part of `common` module.**

```
public interface ChildCommand {
    
    void run(Object sender, String[] args);
    
    String getName();
    
}

public abstract class AbstractCommandService<S> {
    
    protected final Set<ChildCommand> childCommands;
    
    protected AbstractCommandService() {
        childCommands = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public boolean execute(Object sender, String commandName, String[] args) {
        for (ChildCommand childCommand : childCommands) {
            if (childCommand.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(commandName)) {
                childCommand.run(sender, args);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void addCommand(ChildCommand command) {
        childCommands.add(command);
    }
    
}
```

**This classes are part of `bungee` module.**

```
public class BungeeReload implements ChildCommand {

    private final String NAME = "reload";

    public BungeeReload() {}

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    /*how do I structure my code so here I would get `net.md_5.bungee.api.CommandSender` 
    instead of `Object` for the sender parameter.*/
    @Override 
    public void run(Object sender, String[] args) {
        ((CommandSender)sender).sendMessage("Reload command has been ran on bungee.");
    }

}

public class BungeeCommandService extends AbstractCommandService<CommandSender> {}

public class MainBungeeCommand extends Command {

    private BungeeCommandService commandService;    
    
    public MainBungeeCommand() {
        super("cmd-name", "cmd-permission", "cmd-alias");
        commandService = new BungeeCommandService();

        commandService.addCommand(new BungeeReload());
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(CommandSender sender, String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            String commandName = args[0];
           
            boolean successfullyExecuted = commandService.execute(sender, commandName, args);
            if (!successfullyExecuted) sender.sendMessage("Unknown command!"));
        } 
    }
    
}
```

**This classes are part of `bukkit` module.**

```
public class BukkitReload implements ChildCommand {

    private final String NAME = "reload";

    public BukkitReload () {}

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    /*how do I structure my code so here I would get `org.bukkit.command.CommandSender` 
    instead of `Object` for the sender parameter.*/
    @Override 
    public void run(Object sender, String[] args) {
        ((CommandSender)sender).sendMessage("Reload command has been ran on bukkit.");
    }

}

public class BukkitCommandService extends AbstractCommandService<CommandSender> {}

public class MainBukkitCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    private BukkitCommandService commandService;    
    
    public MainBukkitCommand() {
        commandService = new BukkitCommandService();
        commandService.addCommand(new BukkitReload());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            String commandName = args[0];
           
            boolean successfullyExecuted = commandService.execute(sender, commandName, args);
            if (!successfullyExecuted) sender.sendMessage("Unknown command!"));
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }
    
}
```

Here the classes from the APIs.
[CommandSender](https://docs.phoenix616.dev/bungee-api/index.html?net/md_5/bungee/api/CommandSender.html) class from the Bungeecord API.
[Command](https://docs.phoenix616.dev/bungee-api/index.html?net/md_5/bungee/api/plugin/Command.html) class from the Bungeecord API.
[CommandSender](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/command/CommandSender.html) class from the Bukkit API.
[CommandExecutor](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/command/CommandExecutor.html) class from the Bukkit API.